# How to package a library with external references?

Tags: c#, .net, package, nuget

I'm creating a package for NuGet from a library that wraps a console application. How would I supply this console program with the library I am creating? The console .exe needs to be in the same directory as the library **after** the build, but not required during build.

I don't believe I can place it in the "lib" folder as it's not something that the referencing program can actually reference in the first place, and not the "content" folder either since it's needed after the build process, not during.

Am I forced to have to get the user to download the console application separately and supply the filename to the library? Or is there a way that I can easily implement this need in NuGet?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Nuget packages are not meant for deploying executables. The purpose of Nuget is to simplify the deployment of other libraries that you need to include as a reference in your coding projects.  Also I'm not sure what you mean by console application but if this some actual 3rd party console program and not the command prompt in Windows and this meant to go to an end user who just needs to double click and run the application then you either need to create an installer with InstallShield or one of the installers provided with VS. Additionally you could look into chocolatey which is meant for application distribution and deployment.

[Chocolatey](https://chocolatey.org)

Comment: The way the console application works is that the end user uses the library to interface with the command line tool, not the other way round. The library gives the tool arguments and runs it, and handles it all in a managed environment. The user **never** runs the .exe file, the library itself is an interface between the command line tool and the project that references this library.

Comment: Oh I see, well in that case you could just package the exe file into the Nuget package and deploy it like that. Selenium web driver deploys the web driver exes through Nuget. It just copies the exe into the root folder of your package but I think it requires some additional scripting to get it to work.  I've never used Nuget like that though.